# Calling a function in a function

Tags: ros, function

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, can help me to check what is my mistake in the following code please? I did try to refer to http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/UsingClassMethodsAsCallbacks but fail. Thank you.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <visualization_msgs/Marker.h>
#include <pcl/ros/conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>

ros::Subscriber sub_;
ros::Publisher markerpub_;

    class Listener{
      public:
        double publishBbox();
      };
    
    void cloudcb(const PointCloud::ConstPtr&  cloud){
        publishBbox();
    }
    
    double Listener::publishBbox(){
        double x = (min_x_ + max_x_)/2;
        double y = (min_y_ + max_y_)/2;
        double z = (0 + max_z_)/2;
    
        double scale_x = (max_x_ - x)*2;
        double scale_y = (max_y_ - y)*2;
        double scale_z = (max_z_ - z)*2;
    
        visualization_msgs::Marker marker;
        marker.header.frame_id = "/camera_rgb_optical_frame";
        marker.header.stamp = ros::Time();
        marker.ns = "my_namespace";
        marker.id = 1;
        marker.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::CUBE;
        marker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
        marker.pose.position.x = x;
        marker.pose.position.y = -y;
        marker.pose.position.z = z;
        marker.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
        marker.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
        marker.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
        marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
        marker.scale.x = scale_x;
        marker.scale.y = scale_y;
        marker.scale.z = scale_z;
        marker.color.a = 0.5;
        marker.color.r = 0.0;
        marker.color.g = 1.0;
        marker.color.b = 0.0;
        //only if using a MESH_RESOURCE marker type:
        bboxpub_.publish( marker );
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char** argv){
        ros::init(argc, argv, "my_tf_broadcaster");
      
        ros::NodeHandle nh;
      
        sub_= nh.subscribe("camera/depth/points", 1, cloudcb);  
        Listener bbox;
        bboxpub_ = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("bbox",1, &Listener::publishBbox, &bbox);
      
        ros::spin();
        return 0;
    };
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111936/calling-a-function-in-a-function/) by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-12-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VC](https://answers.ros.org/users/999/vc/) on 2013-12-19**:
Could you post the error messages please?

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2013-12-19**:
hi VC, my apologies. the error message was "error: ‘publishBbox’ was not declared in this scope". hav tried the suggestion given by Ben_S and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`cloudcb` is not a member of your class `Listener`. Thats why it won't be possible to call `publishBbox()` from within. Make it a class method and add your object reference to the subscriber like you did for the publisher.

You should also get your variable names right and think about moving the subscriber and publisher into your class, initializing them in the constructor.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2013-12-19**:
Thanks, it worked once i added the publishBbox in the class :)